# Delegating (generic) constraint definition annotation

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

In JSR-303 (Bean Validation) you need to define a special annotation for each constraint validator you write. This makes perfect sense if you are creating reusable constraint validators (like the standard `@Max`, `@NotNull`, etc).

However in real life every validated bean requires its own validator to do more complex business validations. With vanilla JSR-303 implementations you have to create a separate annotation for every validator. This forces developer to write one-time-only annotations and makes the overall concept of bean validation look stupid. The necessity for one-time-only annotations can be avoided if JSR-303 offers some sort of delegating constraint annotation: `@ValidateBy(validator=my.custom.Validator)`.

Now to my question:

- Why doesn't JSR-303 include such use-case?
- Is there any official discussion related to this (I was not able to find anything)?
- Do any JSR-303 library offer such functionality (not that it would be hard to implement that)?

---

**UPDATE 1** - Specific use-case (which led to this question)

We have a moderate enterprise application with pretty rich business model (40 manageable entities, 20 embeddable entities, 25 read-only entities). This means that we have a lots of HTML forms. Each form is backed by a designated form bean (70 form beans) with JSR-303 annotations. Some forms require custom non-trivial validation (e.g. if *delivery type is email* then a *contact email must be set*, ...). With JSR-303 we have 33 form-bean specific validators with 33 (unnecessary one-time-only) annotations.

With the number of Java classes (entities, controllers, DAOs, DTOs, mappers, validators, etc... right now this makes 800 `.java` files) I don't like having any boilerplate code around.

Comment: Good question, maybe they thought that the validation provided by other frameworks (like JSF) is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you need to ask the question to realize how to solve "the problem" yourself. Based on Gunnar's answer and comments:

You can create `@MyDomainModelValid` constriant definition for the custom domain model with all the necessary validators:

```
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy={
        MyFirstEntityValidator.class, MySecondEntityValidator.class,
        MyThirdEntityValidator.class, EtCetera.class})
public @interface MyDomainModelValid {
    String message() default "entity.notValid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

JSR-303 implementation will make sure that a correct validator is called for a specific entity. So there is no need for previously proposed `@ValidatedBy` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

One of the core principles of Bean Validation is type-safety. Specific constraint annotations such as `@Max`, `@Size` allow to specify and access custom attributes such as the allowed maximum value in a type-safe safe manner.

The chosen approach also allows the validation engine to select the right validator implementation based on the annotated element's type instead of requiring the user to specify the validator class. So in a way this shifts complexity a bit from the constraint *user* to the constraint *author*.

As you say, implementing this as a custom constraint should not be difficult. Note though that this disables compile time checking of constraint correctness e.g. via the [annotation processor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-annotation-processor) provided by Hibernate Validator. While this could detect an erronously specified `@Past` constraint on a string property, it couldn't detect a non-matching validator type specified via `@ValidatedBy`.

If your requirement is about custom validation logic for complete beans (class-level validation), you might consider to implement that in a method of that bean as this:

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isValid() {
    //custom validation logic
}
```

Or you might leverage the [@ScriptAssert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-hv-constraints) constraint provided by Hibernate Validator.

Comment: `@AssertTrue` on a single method does not allow for a specific field validation messages (i.e. you can not build your own constraint violations). `@ScriptAssert` is not acceptable alternative. But I see other solution reading your answer - create custom `@BusinessValid` annotation with all the custom validator references inside `validatedBy`. The correct validator would be then chosen during runtime.

Comment: Btw. I understand your answer that you guys did not discuss this use-case in detail (took me a minute to realize you are involved :))? Is the approach described in my previous comment (`@BusinessValid`) correct according to bean-validation principles?

Comment: I think I'd need some more details about your particular requirements to better understand what you're actually after. If the idea is to create a class-level constraint `@BusinessValid` and provide a validator for each entity of your domain, yes that would be the way to go in Bean Validation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another way to reduce boilerplate code is by using [SmartConstraints](https://github.com/jruillier/smartconstraints) (I'm the author).

You could annotate your domain entities fields with regular JSR-303 annotations, and SmartConstraints annotation processor would automatically generate matching `@ValidMyField` annotations that you would reuse in your DTOs.